# Django & Socket Server: Can I add socket server instance to "memory"?

Tags: python, django, sockets

I'm working with:

- Django 1.11
- Python Sockets

I have a Socket server like this:

```
class SocketServer(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, ip="127.0.0.1", port=5000, _buffer=1024):
        super(RoomSocketServer, self).__init__()
        self.IP = ip
        self.PORT = port
        self.RECV_BUFFER = _buffer  # Advisable to keep it as an exponent of 2
        self.CONNECTION_LIST = []  # list of socket clients
        self.MESSAGE_QUEUES = {}  # List of message queue by socket
        self.OUTPUTS = []
        self.SERVER = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        # this has no effect, why ?
        self.SERVER.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.SERVER.bind((self.IP, self.PORT))
        self.SERVER.listen(10)

        # Add server socket to the list of readable connections
        self.CONNECTION_LIST.append(self.SERVER)
        self.ROOM = Room.objects.create(port=port, ip=ip, type_room=type_room)

    def read_sockets(self, read_sockets):
        ''' ... '''

    def write_sockets(self, write_sockets):
        ''' ... '''

    def error_sockets(self, error_sockets):
        ''' ... '''

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            # Get the list sockets which are ready to be read through select
            read_sockets, write_sockets, error_sockets = select.select(self.CONNECTION_LIST, self.OUTPUTS, [])

            # Read sockets
            self.read_sockets(read_sockets)
            self.write_sockets(write_sockets)
            self.error_sockets(error_sockets)

        self.SERVER.close()
```

I can run this SocketServer like this anywhere on Django (custom_command, a view, celery...):

```
from socket_server import SocketServer

socket_server = SocketServer()
socket_server.start()
# And the code continues while the socket server is running
# I would like to save socket_server instance anywhere to access
# Later from anywhere or trigger a signal to finish it
```

Like I say above, I would like to know (if possible) where would any of you save the instance of the server to access it from different parts of the Django project ?

**UPDATE**

I tried using memcached on Django but when I try to store the SocketServer instance on memcached I get this error:

> PicklingError: Can't pickle : attribute lookup thread.lock failed

Comment: Good question, what server is used for or what does stand behind the server in your domain area?

Comment: Django-Channels uses Redis. Maybe Channels is the simpler solution?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I'll check Django-Channels. Right now I'm just checking on local with *manage.py runserver* but later I think I'll have apache or nginx running as web server

Comment: @AlvaroAV, did you find the solution? I am also running a django app which uses ssl socket for connection with firmware and Django rest framework for UI connection. I am also confused what to add in Django files so that it will start socket server.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes and its simple

```
serverlst = dict()
for x in range(0,5):
    tmp = SocketServer("",5000+x) # Note that you should change the port because each port can be listened only by one socket server
    tmp.start()
    serverlst[5000+x]=tmp
```

or you can access to server socket with

```
serverlst[5000].getName()   # returns the server socket with port 5000's thread
```

when you print `serverlst` after loop, you can see this

```
{5000: <SocketServer(Thread-5, started 139741574940416)>, 5001: <SocketServer(Thread-6, started 139741583333120)>, 5002: <SocketServer(Thread-7, started 139741658834688)>, 5003: <SocketServer(Thread-8, started 139741667227392)>, 5004: <SocketServer(Thread-9, started 139741233895168)>}
```

or you can add it to `list()`

#### update

sorry i didn't see

> I would like to know (if possible) where would any of you save the instance of the server to access it from different parts of the Django project

i can say it depends on the way you develop and i think its not a good idea. its better to use a bridge between threads and Django project like [redis](http://redis.io) which allows you to keep data and access it from entire system and you can use [python redis client](https://pypi.org/project/redis/).